# Geo-targeting post on FB page not working

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am able to get my post to show up with the correct link, status, image, etc. but I can't seem to get the targeting to work correctly. Here is what I'm posting in my json targeting field:

```
{
  ...
  message: "test status message",
  targeting: "{"cities":[{"name":"Austin, TX","key":2525495,"subtext":"TX, United States"},    {"name":"San Marcos, TX","key":2529779,"subtext":"TX, United States"},{"name":"Round Rock,   TX","key":2529681,"subtext":"TX, United States"},{"name":"Cedar Park, TX","key":2526105,"subtext":"TX, United States"},{"name":"Georgetown, TX","key":2527173,"subtext":"TX, United States"},{"name":"Blanco, TX","key":2525726,"subtext":"TX, United States"}]}",
  ...
}
```

What I am seeing as a result on my posts is:

```
Shared with: Aixàs, Andorra, Aixàs, Andorra, Aixàs, Andorra, Aixàs, Andorra, Aixàs, Andorra, Aixàs, Andorra
News feed targeting: Aixàs, Andorra, Aixàs, Andorra, Aixàs, Andorra, Aixàs, Andorra, Aixàs, Andorra, Aixàs, Andorra
```

In another test I tried sending the following:

```
{
...
targeting: "{'countries':['US'],'regions':[{'key': 25,'name': 'Massachusetts','country_code': 'US'}]}"
...
}
```

And while the post was published, the result was nothing:

```
Shared with:
```

Can anyone shed some light on this. The first one is interesting in that I am trying to target six cities and getting six copies of a city in Andorra. I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong. I looked at all the documentation and even copied my data from the autocomplte api.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Comment: The first one looks like the string isn't escaped correctly because I copied it from my console log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you now have to use the `feed_targeting` parameter rather than the `targeting` parameter in your post. `targeting` is now used for something referred to as "gating", which not only targets the specified region but restricts their ability to re-share the post with anyone outside the region (commonly used for regional legal/rights concerns).

Additionally, you'll still be unable to target the post unless you use the "page access token" rather than the "user access token", as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens):

> To perform the following operations as a Page, and not the current user, you must use the Page's access token, not the user access token commonly used for reading Graph API objects. This access token can be retrieved by issuing an HTTP GET to /USER_ID/accounts with the manage_pages permission. This will return a list of Pages (including application profile Pages) to which the user has administrative access, along with access_tokens for those Pages. Alternatively, you can get a page access token for a single, specific, page by issuing an HTTP GET to /PAGE_ID?fields=access_token with the manage_pages permission, as described above. Publishing to a Page also requires the publish_stream permission, unless otherwise noted.

Comment: Going from 'targeting' to 'feed_targeting' helps but it isn't the whole story. I am able to get proper targeting when I set feed targeting to {"countries":["US"]}, but I'm unclear of the syntax for cities or even regions. Nothing I have tried has worked. It is just ignored and the post says 'Public'.

Comment: I see the "Aixàs" issue when using the examples in their [targeting specs for ads](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/targeting-specs). But it seems to work when I submit the cities or regions using only their integer key values. So SF and Oakland can be targeted by setting `feed_targeting` to `{'cities':[2421836,2421044]}`, and California with `{'countries':['US'],'regions':[6]}`

Comment: Thanks, AJ! I was able to get cities working by using just an array of IDs. However, I wasn't able to target MA with `{"countries":["US"],"regions":[25]}`. I'll keep trying though. The lack of complete/consistent documentation is frustrating.

Comment: I take back that last bit. Regions are working! Thanks for the help, AJ.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is now probably fixed by moving from targeting to feed_targeting I wanted to share a related problem we encountered because it took us a few hours to discover what was wrong.

We had all gated posts show up at Aixàs, Andorra as well. In our case we were gating on cities which is actually not allowed, you can only gate on country and language. Facebook somehow matches all gating to Aixàs, Andorra, maybe they are the first entries in the table?

When we removed cities from our gating options everything worked fine.